# undoing commit not working per SO thread

Tags: git

I was following this SO question here but something is not working for me...

[How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit)

I do a `git reset --hard HEAD~1` three times and I see the code I want and when I do a git status, it says You branch is behind origin/master by 3 commits and can be fast-forwarded.  Yes, I backed out of 3 commits so that seems good but how do I now commit and push the changes so the latest in master in my remote repo is without the 3 commits.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: So you're actually asking how to update the remote repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run

```
git push --force
```

To force push the remote repo backwards in time.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody has yet pulled the state of your `origin` repo, go with the [answer provided by SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916840/520162).

But if you're not sure about that, forced pushing is not the best idea since it could cause problems with your fellow developers.

To have your last three commits reverted in a way that you could use with `origin`, go with [`git revert`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert). This will create a new commit reverting your already made commits.

If your history looks like this

```
A--B--C--D--E--HEAD
```

and you want to drop `C`, `D` and `E`, revert them in the following sequence

```
git revert E
git revert D
git revert C
```

Then, you'll be 3 commits **ahead** `origin` and you could push without any hassle. If someone already pulled your changes of `C`, `D`, and `E`, they will be removed upon the next `pull`.

---

By the way: this is what the not-accepted answer to your referenced question also recommends:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376039/520162 (**Undo a public commit**)

Comment: Special mention for warning about changing a possibly shared history, and for advising a `git revert`.

Comment: that didn't work, I ended up with conflicts from a merge (ON A REVERT).  I am not sure why git thinks it needs to merge as I just want that exact code base as my latest commit.  ie. this completely did not work :(. thanks though.